# Issue with modifying WindowGroup in SwiftUI lifecycle macOS in removing titlebar and background

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to make my title and background disappear.

I am using the code below for this goal, but it has 2 big issues with it:

- First, there is still some shadow existing from the title.
- Second, when I run my code, for some short time (about 0.1-0.2 sec) it shows a window with background and title and once NotificationCenter sends the notification it start working.

How can I solve this issue?

```
  @main
struct Work_Space_macOSApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.willUpdateNotification), perform: { _ in
                    makeWindow()
                })
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.black)
    }
}

func makeWindow() {
    for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden
        window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.zoomButton)!.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)!.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)!.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The "ghost" titlebar can be dealt with by setting `window.hasShadow = false` in the `makeWindow` function.

Comment: @tromgy: It does not solve the issue.

Comment: Do you still see the shadow of the titlebar?

Comment: Yes, for sure. Have you test your code?

Comment: Surely, the shadow is gone from the title bar, as well as the circle: https://imgur.com/a/hnpQqEF macOS Big Sur 11.6, XCode 13.1

Comment: It is not working bro! Your background does not let you see the shadow! minimize the Xcode then you would be noticed!